# Unable to resume activity: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=0, data=null} to activity

Tags: android

I caught this error in my log today :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {MyProfileActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=0, data=null} to activity {MyProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I don't know what to do since the stacktrace does NOT refer to any of my code and the activity "MyActivity" does not implement onActivityResult().
(Some other activity in my project does but not this one).

Here is the full stacktrace :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {MyActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=0, data=null} to activity {MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2977)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3006)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1334)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=0, data=null} to activity {MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3566)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2960)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzw.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabm.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5521)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3562)
... 13 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=0, data=null} to activity {MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3566)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2960)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3006)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1334)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzw.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabm.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5521)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3562)
... 13 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzw.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabm.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5521)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3562)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2960)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3006)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1334)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: "the activity "MyActivity" does not implement onActivityResult()" -- according to the stack trace, your activity is inheriting from some Play Services SDK-supplied activity, and that is what's crashing. This could be a bug in the Play Services SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @CommonsWare